# Can I set header into JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jwplayer

I tried to use the [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) for play a video in my current project. And for secure our media file on server. I put secure key in the header of the video render action by using javascript.

For example, if I want to request to [http://mydomain.com/video/[myvideoname]/download](http://mydomain.com/video/%5bmyvideoname%5d/download), and I have to put the secure key like **Authorization Bearer f850dae6bb36ffa2f7c07c30fea158ca99e8c237** into the header of the request to server. But I search somewhere on internet, but maybe could not find out any solution to set the request header. Could anyone let me know can I do like this or not ?

Comment: Where are you setting this key?

Comment: I setup the OAuth2 server that provide that secure key. The first time, user have to request the key from that server and store somewhere on the session, when user want to see that video, she need to provide that key in the header of the request.

Comment: Is there an example to where you are trying this?

Comment: Been almost two years, did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm wondering the same thing.